# Python: Control Flow

Tags: python, control-flow

An issue with my existing code. Code goes:

```
example_dic = {'name': 'jim','value': 4}
list_of_dic = [example_dic,dic2,dic3,...]
empty_list = []    #will be filled with multiple dictionaries all in same format/same keys
key_sum = sum(blah['value'] for blah in empty_list)    #tested this with a filled in "list_of_dic", works as expected

if not empty_list or key_sum < arbitrary_value:
    for things in list_of_dic[:]:
        if case1:
            empty_list.append(things)
            list_of_dic.remove(things)
        elif case2:
            empty_list.append(things)
            list_of_dic.remove(things)
        else:
            pass
```

Problem is that `key_sum` does not get updated ever even though things are being appended onto `empty_list`. As I said in the comments, I know the `key_sum` line works because I tried it by filling in the list of dictionaries with random stuff first.

What I want is that items will keep being added onto `list_of_dic` only while `key_sum < arbitrary`. If for example I want `key_sum < 20`, if the next item causes `key_sum >= 20`, I do not want it to be added at all, not simply break and end after it's already been added. I also do not want the code to end there, if there is a list of 10 items and the 1st one has `value = 22` I don't want the whole thing to stop, I want it to keep going through the rest, adding items on until it cannot add anymore that wouldn't cause `key_sum >= 20`.

Simpler answer would be, is there any other language which doesn't require such unnecessary complication for what seems like a very simple task?

Comment: Those are not static declarations, they are operations that are executed in order. Hence the value written to a variable will remain there until explicitly changed. It is not the definition of key_sum that it contains the list of all value fields from the empty list.

Comment: Being completely honest, I understand just about nothing of what you said. What is "those" referring to? Why would I want anything to be static, I want 'key_sum' to not be static? By simply switching the 'if not empty_list...' statement with the 'for things in list_of...', 'key_sum' does update, but the whole loop fails to obey the 'key_sum' < arbitrary_value statement.

Comment: Sorry, let me try to explain better. The point is that many people learn maths first, where the order of some connected statements doesn't matter. If you switch `x = 1` and `y = x` around, nothing changes and `y` equals `1` equals `x` all the time. Programs however are executed top to bottom and those are not equations but assignments, so there the order matters. So, even though Python and math share a partially similar syntax, the meaning behind it is different.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with this. One is that your code assumes that `key_sum` gets automatically updated when you change `empty_list`, but that's not the case. It just gets calculated once. You'll need to recalculate `key_sum` on every iteration, or if you're really worried about efficiency, increment the `key_sum` every time you append to `empty_list`. It also seems like you want to check the value of `key_sum` on every iteration of your for loop, rather than only after you've iterated over the entire `list_of_dic`.

The second issue is that you're removing items from `list_of_dic` while you iterate over it. This has undefined behavior in Python, and generally results in certain elements of your iterable being skipped over. Instead, you need to iterate over a copy of the list.

Summarizing the changes:

```
for things in list_of_dic[:]:  # Iterate over a copy of list_of_dic
    do_append = False
    if case1:
        do_append = True
    elif case2:
        do_append = True

    if do_append:
        if (key_sum + things['value']) >= arbitrary_value:
            continue
        empty_list.append(things)
        list_of_dic.remove(things)
        key_sum += things['value']
```

Comment: Your suggestions solved the issue of removal, so thank you for that, but it didn't solve the 'key_sum' problem. It still continues to go far exceeding the arbitrary value I set it lower to. How would incrementing work? Wouldn't I need to declare 'key_sum' again somewhere?

Comment: @awar I think I understand what you're looking for now. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah yes that seems to be more along what I was looking for. I will give this a try, but before I do, should the last if statement ('get_sum(d) < arbitrary') be '>=' instead of '<'? And wouldn't it be better for it to be above 'if case1:' so it will execute before?

Comment: @awar Yes, I've fixed that first typo already. I put the size check at the end of the loop because when you initially enter the for loop, your `key_sum` will never be above `arbitrary_value`. It's just a small optimization to only check if we *are* above it after we know we may have appended an entry to `empty_list`. Also, it looks like you never expect to iterate over `list_of_dic` more than one time, right? In that case, you don't need the `if` statement outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: What if I do want to iterate over more than once, just leave it? This still fails to work, it seems to break only after it has added the dictionary that causes sum >= arbitrary, how do I tell it to not add it at all if it exceeds?

Comment: Apologies, I think I should've clarified more what I wanted from this code, I clarified in the last paragraph in my original question.